# Big Query data transfer error 3764448 for cross region dataset copy

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting "**internal error 3764448**" when performing cross dataset copy from us-central1 to asia-southeast1.

It was working for months and all of the sudden it started throwing errors last 3 days. Dataset copy within region works fine. Anyone experienced this and what is the issue and workaround?

Comment: You can copy datasets in the same region or across regions. See Supported regions for more information about supported regions. Link -> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#supported_regions

Comment: @Mr.Batra Yes I am aware of that, as I mentioned it was working for months, it is definitely an issue on Google end as I tested more. 1 out of 3 of my transfer has started working, and another 1 worked once or twice and continued failing.